# compare 2 arrays using keys and subtract the values based on keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, subtraction

I have 2 arrays with keys and values, want to subtract 2 array values based on keys,

Below code is, What i have tried,
first array (with key and values):

```
   $bulk_service_vals_id4 =  '101,102,103,104'; 
    $new_bulk_service_vals_id4 = explode(',',$bulk_service_vals_id4); 

    $bulk_service_vals4 =  '2,1,3,2'; 
    $new_bulk_service_vals4 = explode(',',$bulk_service_vals4);
```

Second Array (With key and values):

```
    $booked_service_id =  '101,101,104,103,104'; 
    $new_booked_service_id = explode(',',$booked_service_id); 
    print_r(array_unique($new_booked_service_id));  
    $book_unique_service_id = array_unique($new_booked_service_id);

    $book_unique_service_val = array();
    foreach($book_unique_service_id as $new_booked_service_idss)    
    {
        //echo $new_booked_service_idss;
         $book_unique_service_val[] = substr_count($booked_service_id,$new_booked_service_idss).'<br>';
    }   
    print_r($book_unique_service_val);
```

Combine two arrays:

```
    $key_val1 =array_combine($new_bulk_service_vals_id4,$new_bulk_service_vals4);
    print_r($key_val1);
    $key_val2 =array_combine($book_unique_service_id,$book_unique_service_val);
    print_r($key_val2);
```

output of first array key with values:

```
   key : 101,102,103,104
   values: 2,1,3,2
```

output of second array key with values:

```
  key: 101,104,103
  values: 2,2,1
```

i want to get the final output like tihis format:

```
 key: 101,102,103,104
 values: 0,1,2,0
```

please do my needs.

@Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

$a1 and $a2 are the two arrays.

```
$result = array();

foreach($a1 as $k => $v)
    $result[$k] = array_key_exists($k, $a2) ? $v - $a2[$k] : $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach and check if the key from the first array exists in the second array. If it does, subtract the value:

```
$key_val1 = [
    101 => 2,
    102 => 1,
    103 => 3,
    104 => 2
];

$key_val2 = [
    101 => 2,
    104 => 2,
    103 => 1
];

foreach ($key_val1 as $key => &$value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $key_val2)) {
        $value -= $key_val2[$key];
    }
}
unset ($value);

print_r($key_val1);

Array
(
    [101] => 0
    [102] => 1
    [103] => 2
    [104] => 0
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/osANs)